# Vertx automated deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jvm, vert.x, autodeploy

I've been recently exploring Vertx documentation and was wondering what are the **common  automated deployment strategies** for **Vertx** application ?

Let's assume I've written my app in serveral languages.

**Verticle1:    vertictles/1verticle.js**

**Verticle2:    verticles/2verticle.rb**

**Verticle3:    verticles/3verticle.java**

From the documentation I've found only this:

// deploy java verticle   via hierachy path:

vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyOrderProcessorVerticle");

// Deploy a JavaScript verticle

**vertx.deployVerticle("verticles/1verticle.js");**

// Deploy a Ruby verticle verticle

**vertx.deployVerticle("verticles/2verticle.rb");**

// Deploy a Java verticle verticle

**vertx.deployVerticle("verticles/3verticle.java");**

So how do I automate deployment?

Do I just create some    main deployment file like  app.java with the contents mentioned above and then just run it with vertx cli  ?

**$ vertx run java:app.java          ?**

Another question, what happens exactly underneath when we deploy  a mixture of  JS, RB and JAVA   Verticles ?

Does it compile everything into JVM byte code?

Or does it just interpret the script files  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it might just work if you deploy it from some   main app file  like  app.java including there the deployment path to files programmatically:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("path-to-verticle/someVerticle.js");

vertx.deployVerticle("path-to-verticle/someVerticle.rb");

vertx.deployVerticle("path-to-verticle/someVerticle.ceylon");
```